# How to constrain height of TextInputLayout inside constraint layout so it has enough space for the .setError to show as well?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a `TextInputLayout` inside a `ConstraintLayout` with an `AutoCompleteTextView` inside instead of `EditText`. How can you set the `height constraint` so the error will fit when you need to ? So far, if I use constant height dp... the error won't show up... I'm force to use `wrapContent` on the height... and this way, when you use `.setError` the `TextInputLayout` automatically resizes at runtime to make room for the error.

However this behaviour is undesirable... I want the `TextInputLayout` to have fix height with enough room for the error.

Comment: what if you try `minHeight` for your case?

Comment: Thank you, damn... I can't believe I missed this. However I can't seem to accept your answer as correct.